# Can I create and manipulate unix "screens" in a script?

Tags: linux, unix, scripting, gnu-screen

I have a work environment on my Ubuntu laptop in which I want to use three different screens.

Eg. in terminal, I usually write

```
screen -S mywork
run_server_1
```

then, ctrl-a c to create a second screen

```
run_server_2
```

etc.

I'd like to write a script to automate setting up this environment, but how can I control multiple screens from one script?

Update : I really want to be able to do this from a shell script, not a screen config. file. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading [man pages](http://linuxmanpages.com/man1/screen.1.php) and [tutorials](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6340?page=0,1) helps

I would say that you want to do is create a file $HOME/.screenrc.multiwin

```
# read in your normal screenrc
# before anything else
source $HOME/.screenrc
# now start opening windows
# it's possible to set the window title with
# the -t option
# you can also specify the window number
# to launch in
screen -t server1 5 run_server_1
screen -t server2 6 run_server_2
```

Then running

```
screen -c $HOME/.screenrc.multiwin
```

will do what you need

Comment: Actually, I don't think this is what I want. I really would like to do this in a shell script in which I can do other things too. (And call like any other script.) Not just in a screen "configuration" file.

Comment: @interstar: run_server_1 can be another script. The above is relatively flexible if the scripts are independent.
Alternatively if there is a lot of control flow/interprocess communication what about the following: don't start screens but just start servers with their output redirected to files, then in other terminals/screens you can watch those files.

Comment: You can always generate a config to a temporary file and give that file to screen using -c . Since shell scripts are turing complete, it is possible to do almost anything this way, but probably not very easy.

Answer (score 2):

Commands can be passed from outside using `screen -S sessionname -X command` for instance `screen -S mywork -X screen run_server_2` would create a new window (same as `ctrl-a c`) but that window would have run_server_2 executing in it.  Unlike doing it by hand,there will not be a shell running in that window, so when run_server_2 exits, the window will be closed.

Controlling multiple screens is simply a matter of making sure they're all named with -S

Comment: I believe this answer is more universal since it doesn't involve specific mechanisms (like screen's special configuration files), but plain shell scripting.

Answer (score 1):

I believe **tmux** is much more easily scriptable than screen for this type of purpose.  tmux program accepts its own commands as arguments on the command line, so for example, to launch two windows: "tmux new-session -d '/bin/bash' \; new-window -d 'top'". In the first window, it will run an interactive "bash" shell, and in the second window it will run "top".

Comment: Perhaps you could show how?

Comment: Sure. the tmux program accepts its own commands as arguments on the command line, so to launch a single window you type

Comment: Sure. the tmux program accepts its own commands as arguments on the command line, so to launch two windows for example: "tmux new-session -d '/bin/bash' \; new-window -d 'top'"

Comment: If you edit your answer you can add that to it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me

## creates new screen session 'mywork' + runs cmd 'run_server_1' in a window titled 'server_1'

```
screen -dmS mywork -t server_1 sh -c "run_server_1"
```

## automates ctrl-a c to create a second screen window titled 'server_2' and runs cmd 'run_server_2'

```
screen -S mywork -t server_2  -X screen run_server_2
```